# Is it possible to use multiple catch blocks in user defined exception?

Tags: java

I am just confused  whether it is possible to use multiple catch blocks in user defined exceptions

Comment: What do you mean by "user defined" exception?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking at all. Perhaps a relevant code sample would be helpful in clarifying?

Comment: It is always possible to use multiple catch blocks. Did you even try?

Comment: Hey james K Polk user defined in the sense custom Exception

Comment: hey marstran i am aware of using multiple catch blocks, i am asking that in custom exceptions,the exceptions which are defined by user

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible to use multiple catch blocks from Java 7+.

You can do this to implement specific scenarios that are performed given a specific error that is encountered. For example:
*From: [Jenkov.com](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/catching-multiple-exceptions.html)*

```
try {

    // execute code that may throw 1 of the 3 exceptions below.

} catch(SQLException | IOException e) {
    logger.log(e);

} catch(Exception e) {
    logger.severe(e);
}
```

Comment: I'd prefer to see SQLException | IOException if the catch body is the same. Methinks you're teaching a beginner bad habits.

Comment: @Bathsheba I did not write this example, as stated in my answer.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that the example is a poor one.

Comment: @Bathsheba Then provide an alternative? Updated

Comment: Especially notice @EvanBechtol saying _from Java 7+_ as before it was not possible.